# Unity 3D Sphere penetrating cloth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I imported an fbx cube from blender with a lot of vertices to Unity. I added the constraints and set the sphere collider to my sphere game object. The problem is that regardless of the sphere's mass and other Rigidbody settings, the sphere still penetrates the cloth even if i set the stretch and bending stiffness both to 1. I tried tweaking other cloth settings but to no avail. What should i do please? Thanks.

[Cloth Issue](https://i.gyazo.com/54567ea3a453a86aa34b2d63a3198508.mp4)